# Apply group policy user configuration to all users

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy

I'm using Windows 7 and I've made some changes through gpedit.msc to the User configuration > Administrative Template tree and now I need those changes applied to every user on the local machine.

How can I update all of the user's group policy settings to reflect the ones I've already entered under an admin account?

Comment: The policies should affect all users, and should be applied next time they log in. Are you not finding that to be true?

Comment: I found that is what is happening, but I'm trying to find a way to update them without having each user log in.

Comment: You can't.  User-level policies aren't applied until the user is active (since their personal HKCU Registry hive isn't loaded until they log in, for one).  Once they log in, it will be applied to their account.  I'm not sure what scenario there'd be an advantage to assigning the policies before they log in?

Comment: I figured that was the case. Not all of the users log on that often and was wondering if I could update it without having them log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-level policies aren't (and in general, can't be) applied until the user is active (since their personal Registry hive isn't loaded until they log in, for one reason).

Once they log in, the policies will be applied to their user account.